# I need to display data from a list of json with every key as a seperate column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, mariadb

I am using **Maria Db** or **PostgreSQL** as my databases.

I have created a table with a single column which is json type.

```
CREATE TABLE sample(jsondata json);
```

And in that column i am inserting a list of jsons which are similar to each other and only the values are different.

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES('[{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}, {"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}]');
```

I want to fetch my result from a single query that displays the keys such as here **Date**, **TableName** and **Count** as separate columns and the there values gets displayed into respective rows so here will be three separate rows.
I have tried multiple functions `json_value`, `json_extract` and many more but still not able to figure it out.

Can anyone provide a solution using a function in Maria DB or by changing the structure of Json?

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: using json_value(jsondata ,'$.Date) gives result for the upcoming data gives a single row entry with only null values. And if we insert json without the square brackets in front and end json_value(jsondata,'$.Date')  will give the values for the first json only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function for `PostgreSQL`:

```
select js ->> 'Date' as Date, js ->> 'TableName' as TableName, js ->> 'Count' as Count 
  from
  (
    select json_array_elements(jsondata) as js
      from sample
  ) q
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=a36b3aa7c678f6bd07e7aca3f9f47642)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the response. It worked fine. Can you tell me the same approach for MariaDB also?

Comment: you're welcome @A.Yadav . You can look up `JSON_OBJECT()` function for mySQL database group such as MariaDB.

Comment: while using json_object() function for mySQL database with a entry such as  i have mentioned above, i am getting " Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'json_object' ". I have tried other ways of input like removing the square braces, wrapping data in ' ', and using curly braces around the data but none of that worked.

Comment: So i used this query: 
select json_object(js,'Date'), json_object(js,'TableName'), json_object(js,'Count') from ( select json_array(jsondata) as js from sample1) q;
And the result i get was somelike this :
 {"[\"{'{\\\"Date\\\": \\\"2019-09-30\\\", \\\"TableName\\\": \\\"es_apn_1\\\", \\\"Count\\\": \\\"3\\\"}', '{\\\ 
... in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting data properly. Here is how you should be inserting the data:

```
INSERT INTO sample
VALUES ('{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_apn_1", "Count": "3"}'),
       ('{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_response_1", "Count": "297"}'),
       ('{"Date": "2019-09-30", "TableName": "es_group_1", "Count": "356"}');
```

And to get the desired output you can do this:

```
SELECT jsondata -> 'Date' AS Date, jsondata -> 'TableName' AS TableName, jsondata -> 'Count' AS Count FROM sample;
```

You can check the working example here: [db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=982063970ca6ff398b75de5c7a78f36c)

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Comment: I have already used this format before and i knew it works easily but due to some design issues i have to change my format to a single json. By the way, thanks for your response.